# Auto-vectorization of loop containing comparisons

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vectorization

I'm trying to use the Visual C++ 2013 auto-vectorizer to make the following loop vectorized (`/arch:AVX2`) but the compiler refuses and gives the following message:

```
info C5002: loop not vectorized due to reason '1100'
```

This [reason code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658585.aspx#BKMK_ReasonCode110x) means

```
Loop contains control flow—for example, "if" or "?".
```

I have tried to split the comparisons and the final assignment into a separate loop but that seems inefficient when there are [intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cmp&techs=AVX&expand=693,693) available for performing comparisons on floating point values.

Why should the compiler treat comparisons as flow control, and what can I change in the implementation so that the compiler will vectorize this function?

```
void triplets_positive(
    const std::uint64_t count,
    double * const a,
    double * const b,
    double * const c,
    std::uint64_t * const all_positive)
{
    for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        // These >= operations make the loop not vectorisable because
        // they introduce control flow.
        std::uint64_t a_pos = (a[i] >= 0.0);
        std::uint64_t b_pos = (b[i] >= 0.0);
        std::uint64_t c_pos = (c[i] >= 0.0);

        all_positive[i] = a_pos & b_pos & c_pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: VS 2017 seems to.

Comment: I assume the evaluation of `c_pos` has a typo.

Comment: @Peter, whoops, yes. Thanks. Fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this appears to be either a bug or limitation in the Visual C++ 2013 compiler. Other compilers make use either of the [CMPPD](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cmp&techs=AVX&expand=693,693) instruction (AVX/AVX2) or [CMP*PD](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=cmp&techs=SSE2&expand=693,693,967,845) instructions (SSE2).

Compilers that successfully vectorise this loop include:

- Visual C++ 2017
- Visual C++ 2015
- Clang + LLVM (`Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)`)

While it's theoretically possible to write the comparison as bitwise operations, that's counterproductive and the best option is to upgrade to another compiler.

Comment: And what about gcc?